# Order of formula in glm() change the results

Tags: r, glm, anova, chi-squared

I noticed in the `glm()` function the order of factors can change the results, but I don't understand why:

```
mydata      <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv") #example
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)


# gpa was at the 2nd place
my.mod <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
anova(my.mod, test="Chisq")$"Pr(>Chi)"
[1]           NA 1.907193e-04 1.684783e-02 7.088456e-05


# here, rank was at the 2nd place
my.mod <- glm(admit ~ gre + rank + gpa, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
anova(my.mod, test="Chisq")$"Pr(>Chi)"
[1]           NA 1.907193e-04 8.191817e-05 1.419044e-02
```

Normally coupling a logistic regression (glm) to an anova/chi2 makes it possible to look for the factors that most influence the dataset while weighting the others (factors), in an independent way isn't it ?

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15307) over at Cross Validated?

Comment: That anova table p-value is comparing whether that row is different from the model using all the rows before it. It does depend on order. If you look at the `summary()` of both those models, you will see they both give the same coefficients and p-values for the individual terms. What p-value are you looking for exactly? What's the test you are trying to perform? This might also be relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13241/the-order-of-variables-in-anova-matters-doesnt-it

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Lyngbakr and @MrFlick.
It is now more clear. But now it make me doubt about how I analyze my data haha. I ask for it in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050074/r-analysis-of-frequencies-with-sliding-window-on-glm-and-anova). Anyway thanks again !